# Need query to combine 3 table data on common column basis?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables I need any join condition so that all data from all tables should appear in output as a result.

Table 1 : Common column name: Folio iss_code

Table 2 : Common column name: Folio iss_code

Table 3 : Common column name: Folio 1 Folio 2 iss_code 1 iss_code 2

Select * from table1, table2, table3
Where table1.folio = table2.folio
And table1.folio =any(table3.folio1, table3.folio2);

Is above code is correct..

Please reply

Comment: Please update your question and show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hint: you need a `JOIN`

Comment: I am update the query ... Please reply

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select * from table3 a 
join table1 b on a.folio1=b.folio and a.iss_code1=b.iss_code
join table2 c on a.folio2=c.folio and a.iss_code2=c.iss_code
```